# C# ComboBox on Child Form Not Updating

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a ComboBox on a child form (Form2) whose DataSource needs to be changed. When I try it out on the parent (Form1), I can update the CB by nulling it first:

```
var FilteredList = new List<Tag>();
FilteredList = ApplyFilter(OriginalList);

comboBox1.DataSource = null;
comboBox1.DataSource = FilteredList;
```

That works perfectly. However, the same code on the child form doesn't work. The data is there. I can browse the new items in a breakpoint, but the cb on the form is empty. I've even tried refreshing and calling DoEvents():

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
comboBox1.DataSource = FilteredList;
this.Refresh();
Application.DoEvents();
```

I also tried invoking the change, but either that didn't work, or I didn't do it correctly.

```
comboBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { comboBox1.DataSource = FilteredList; });
```

Here's the Tag class:

```
public class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Station { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that calls the first snippet? Are you calling new on the child form before that code?

Comment: It's called on a button click event on the form. The first snippet was just a test on my part that it would work on Form1. The button and combobox are on the same form. I call Form2 from Form1 when a button is clicked.

Comment: Please show that code. If you create another instance of Form2 but never show it then this explain everything

Comment: @Steve Here's that part. I already had code in there that limits it to a single instance.

Form2Open is a bool that's initially false, is set when Form2 opens, and is cleared when Form2 closes. form2 is a global var in Form1.

    `pbAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Form2Open)
        {
            form2.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            Form2Open = true;
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
        }
    }`

Comment: I found part of the problem. I had the `Sorted` property set to True. Changing it to false is letting me (partially) update the combobox. The new items are in there now, but they're all showing up as blanks.

Comment: When you set the DataSource property you cannot directly change the Items collection. The two approaches (Items.Add and DataSource=...) are mutually exclusive. More. When you use the DataSource you should also set the DisplayMember and the ValueMember to inform the ComboBox how to show your Tag list. The ToString method doesn't apply here. Set DisplayMember = "Name";

Comment: @Steve  Yeah, I've only been changing the cb data by changing between the two different data sources - so that part was ok. It was the DisplayMember part that was missing. Setting that seems to have fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same issue, when setting the `comboBox1.DataSource` to a new list of objects, you need to update the `comboBox1.DisplayMember` setting as well. Here's my final code:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
comboBox1.DataSource = FilteredList;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```